# NLog VS Windows.Identity.Impersonate()

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nlog, impersonation, rights

We have a WEB API app which logs according to levels of

1. **Info**
2. **Debug** and
3. **Error**

Each *log level* is logged to a different file e.g. **[** `"Info"` => *Info.log*; `"Debug"` => *Debug.log*; `"Error"` => *Error.log* **]**.
During development, these were working.

**However** when deployed to **another environment**, **`Error`** was not logged.
We know an application error has occurred as the API call returned **status 500**.
There were logs for `Info` and `Debug`. But none for **`Error`**

After some detective work, we narrowed down that **`Error`** wasn't *logging* as
it was thrown inside an `Impersonation` `using(){}` **block**.

```
var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

logger.Info("Some info message.");    // works
logger.Debug("Some debug params.");   // works

var wid = User.Identity as System.Security.Principal.Windows.Identity;
using(wid.Impersonate())
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Something happened.");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.Error(e, e.Message); // not logging.
    }
}
```

We deduced that the impersonated user doesn't have the rights to ***write*** to the log location.
We confirmed that `Error` was working by changing the *log levels* for `Error` **from**:

```
<rules>
    <!-- no logs -->
    <logger name="Error" minlevel="Error"  maxlevel="Error" writeTo="errorLogFile" />

    <!-- log files created and written to -->
    <logger name="Info"  minlevel="Info"  maxlevel="Info" writeTo="infoLogFile" />
    <logger name="Debug" minlevel="Debug" maxlevel="Debug" writeTo="debugLogFile" />
</rules>
```

**to**:

```
<rules>
    <!-- log files created and written to -->
    <logger name="Error" minlevel="Info"  maxlevel="Error" writeTo="errorLogFile" />

    <!-- log files created and written to -->
    <logger name="Info"  minlevel="Info"  maxlevel="Info" writeTo="infoLogFile" />
    <logger name="Debug" minlevel="Debug" maxlevel="Info" writeTo="debugLogFile" />
</rules>
```

My question is, is there a way to ***Escape*** the `Impersonation` that our errors would be logged as per `Info` and `Debug`?
We can't grant log write privileges to the users as that's not in our purview.

Kindly note that example above is simplified. In the actual implementation, there are additional method calls calls within the `try{}` block with their own `try{}catch{}` and ***logging***.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea for a target-wrapper (that escapes current impersonation). Maybe something can be done with https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ImpersonatingWrapper-target You are welcome to create a pull-request at https://github.com/NLog/NLog/

Comment: What happens if you use AsyncWrapper or just `<targets async="true">` ? (Would think the background timer-thread would not inherit the thread-user-context of the logging thread).

Comment: @RolfKristensen Will try out `<targets async="true">` and update later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the exception out of the impersonation scope.

So not:

```cs
using(wid.Impersonate())
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Something happened.");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.Error(e, e.Message); // not logging.
    }
}
```

But

```
try
{
    using (wid.Impersonate())
    {
        throw new Exception("Something happened.");
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    logger.Error(e, e.Message); // not logging.
}
```

or rethrow and log:

```
try
{
    using (wid.Impersonate())
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Something happened.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // do something;
            throw; //rethrow for logging;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    logger.Error(e, e.Message); // not logging.
}
```

Comment: The reason for impersonation is actually for KERBEROS call to db. We have created a static method for db calls and wrapped impersonation inside the try block of that method. Initial tests seems to be working. Thanks.

Comment: In essence its basically your second code block. We cant the 3rd code block as there are calls to other methods. And if we call it inside of the `Impersonation`, nothing get logged when things goes wrong for those methods.